# How do i set up a sql query where the parameters are pulled from a DropDownList, but by default, no filtering is done by query?

Tags: asp.net, sql

I have no problem creating sql queries where the value for the parameter comes from a control (dropdownlist).  However, how do i adjust my query and set up the dropdown list, so that when page first loads, no value is used as a parameter?  For instance, say i was to create a gridview that filters by state.  The dropdownlist contains a listing of states to filter by.  However, lets say i wanted to include a value called "All States", and have it be the default, and the gridfview show all states?

Comment: Are you just using `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand`?

Comment: I am using a SqlDataSource in Microsoft Web Developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using the `SqlDataSource` control; I think your best bet is to create a stored procedure and use that.  You can then set a "default" parameter value, and set that to something like "All".  Then your stored procedure can do the logic behind figuring out how to craft the "WHERE".

AFAIK the `SqlDataSource` doesn't have the ability to change or omit parameters.

**EDIT**

There is more information [here](http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/using-parameterized-queries-with-the-sqldatasource-vb) about setting default values for the parameters.  This is pretty straight forward.

As far as your stored procedure, you would want it to accept a parameter, probably a string, and it would then decide whether or not to use a `WHERE` clause, similar to this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetStatesFromParameter
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @state nvarchar(MAX) = 'All'
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF @state = 'All'
    BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM States
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM States WHERE Name = @state
    END
END
GO
```

Comment: How would i set a default parameter with a sp?  I can create the sp, i have never set a default parameter up though.  Are you saying that instead of saying "Where States = @States", you would say "Where States = 'All'"  I am not quite sure i understand.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a stored procedure and use an optional parameter, like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetSomeData](
    @Col1 INT = NULL --@Col1 being the value of the DDL
) AS

SET NOCOUNT ON
BEGIN

    SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3
    FROM   SomeTable
    WHERE  (@Col1 IS NULL OR Col1 = @Col1)

END
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this in the dropdownlist databound event:

```
Protected Sub MyDDL_OnDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyDDL.DataBound
    If Not Page.IsPostBack() Then
       DirectCast(sender, DropDownList).Items.Insert(-1, New ListItem("--All States--",0)) 
    End If
End Sub
```

Then in your stored procedure.  Check for an incoming state value of 0 to return all of them.